# How to Change Text Color in PWA Splash Screen

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

How to change the name text color in splash screen progressive web app

```js
"name": "Sanjana",
"short_name": "Sanjana",
```

Comment: @charlietfl look at this first image here https://medium.com/@applification/progressive-web-app-splash-screens-80340b45d210 when you download a PWA on your mobile phone or desktop and you start it you see that splash screen and he wants to change that text color. in your webmanifest you can define the theme color, background color, text and few more other options but not the text color. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Manifest

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, if you found some solution or workaround please share it

Answer (score 1):

There is no mention on how to change the app name text color on the splash screen.